# Google chrome seems not to support a Delete request from an asp.page

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, razor-pages-crud

On a razor page called Days.cshtml I have the following tag inside a form tag:

```html
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" style="width:100%;margin:1px"
       value=" @Localizer["Delete"]" 
       asp-page-handler="Delete" 
       asp-route-personId="@Model.Person.Id" 
       asp-route-from="@from" asp-route-to="@to"
       class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"/>
</form>
```

This is the function that is called when the user clicks the submit button on the form:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDelete(int personId, DateTime from, DateTime to)
    { 
      ...
    }
```

This works fine on the new Edge browser and on Firefox, but Chrome gives the following error:

> This localhost page cannot be found: https://localhost:44335/People/Days?personId=1&from=29-6-2020%2000%3A00%3A00&to=3-7-2020%2000%3A00%3A00&handler=Delete

What is going on?

It seems that Chrome is interpreting the `submit` action as a `Get` request instead of a `Delete` post.

I notice too that the `@from` and `@to`variables, which are `DateTime` values are passed as day-month-year. Can this be related to the problem? Google Chrome is the only browser that recognizes that I am using Dutch. Edge and Firefox display the English resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it: Chrome does not seem to like the `asp-route-xx` approach. When I pass the parameters for the `OnPostDelete` function as hidden `input`tags, it does work. Or it must be that Chrome interprets the `submit` action as a `Get` request because the form was empty apart from the `submit` button.

```html
<form method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="personId" value="@Model.Person.Id" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="from" value="@from" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="to" value="@to"/>
                        <input type="submit" style="width:100%;margin:1px"
                               value=" @Localizer["Delete"]"
                               asp-page-handler="Delete"
                               onclick="return confirm('Weet u zeker dat u de periode van @from.ToShortDateString() tot @to.ToShortDateString() wilt verwijderen?')"
                               class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" />
                    </form>
```